# how to make sure the item in the mongodb array is unique when using the $push operator

Tags: mongodb

I am designing a mongodb application with entity of class and students.

```
var student_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age : String
})
var class_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,                 
    students : []
});
```

In this schema, it is obvious that a class could have more than one students, but each student in the class is unique.

```
var query = {name:class_name};
var update = {"$push":{ 'students': {'name': student_name}; 
model.update(query, update,option,function(err,data){
    if(err) callback(err);
    else callback(null,data);       
});
```

Here I just add the student into the class list with $push, but $push operator doesn't check the uniqueness of the item in the list, meaning I could add the same student twice in the list.

How could I prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $push you can use the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator that ensures that there are no duplicate items added.